# Inventory decreases by 1 even if order was cancelled

Tags: configuration, magento, e-commerce, inventory

Which configuration should I change in order to increase the inventory of a product back to what it was if the order was cancelled?

Thanks,

Comment: Voting ti migrate the question to Webmasters, because this is not a programming question but a question about how to configure a webshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to the admin and change `System>Config>Catalog>Inventory>Stock Options>Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled` = `Yes`. That should do it for you.